# How do I use Views Global Filter with Geofield 2.x Exposed Proximity Filter?

Tags: views, location

I am trying to set it up so that a views global filter  https://drupal.org/project/global_filter can set the distance and city for the proximity filter for Geofield? What are the steps to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Add a filter that precedes that filter that is not exposed and creates the initial filter you want. Usually you can do this with most views handler filters, so it *should* work with the proximity filter.